# Relocation Table and IDA

Tags: windows, portable-executable, ida

I've opened some Windows `PE file` in `IDA` but can't find a `.reloc` (the `Relocation Table`) in `Program Segmentation` window. Did `IDA` just removed this section because when i open the exact same file in `PE-bear` or `CFF Explorer` the `.reloc` section is of course present! What did happened with it in `IDA`?